# Printing a hash to a file

Tags: python, file

I have a function like this to print a user's file {'a': 1,'b': 2} to a new file like abc.txt, but I don't know how to add the infile and outfile correctly. Can someone help me? And if I want to replace the for loop to make it simpler, how can I do that?

```
 def pretty_printing(dict):

        order_keys = dict.keys()
        order_keys.sort()

        for key in order_keys:
            print key, dict[key]
```

Comment: Looking at how you are using it, it seems like the parameter you call `file` is meant to be a Python `dict`. Can you be a bit more specific about what you need to accomplish?

Comment: like when I use this , I just can print a specific string.But I want to apply this in a file like infile=open(file,'r'), outfile=open('example.txt','w'). I want the function print from the user file to the new file.

Comment: What do you want to output to a new file exactly?

Comment: the user's file contains:{'a':1,'b':2}, the new file contains: a   1(line 1) ,b   2(the next line, line 2)

Answer (score 0):

To write output to `'example.txt'`, start with this:

```
with open('example.txt', 'w') as out_file:
  out_file.write(' ... whatever you want to write to the file ...\n')
```

To join sorted `key, dict[key]` string into lines, do this:

```
'\n'.join(['%s, %s' % item for item in sorted(dict.items())])
```

If that's too complicated for you, do this:

```
for (key, value) in sorted(dict.items()):
  out_file.write('%s %s\n' % (key, value))
```

Putting it all together:

```
def pretty_print(dict):
  with open('example.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for (key, value) in sorted(dict.items()):
      out_file.write('%s %s\n' % (key, value))

h = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
pretty_print(h)
```

Comment: can we write in the simpler way because i'm just a new leaner. That code is too complicated for me. And what I mean is I will allow the user to input their file like:new_file=raw_input("enter your file:") and the output will be in the example.txt

Comment: Do you mean that the user would enter the file name? So if I enter `example.txt`, the output gets written to a file of that name?

Comment: yes, the user will enter their own file like a.txt or a.py ...And the function will print a new specific file which I name like example.txt.Overall, there is 1 file from user and there is a new file created in the same place.

Comment: What is supposed to be in `a.txt`?

Comment: That is just an example, a file'name of user, it could be anything,and it contains a content as {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3....}

Comment: I simplified the writing code. It's generally a bad idea to evaluate plain text as a Python value. You should pickle the value instead. If you insist on your approach, do `print('Enter name of input file: ')` and then `h = eval(open(raw_input()).read())` followed by `pretty_print(h)`.

Comment: But I have just learnt about string,list,file and dictionaries, so I don't know how to do with another stuff like eval or %.Do you have a solution in a simple way?

Comment: There is no simpler way to get a Python value out of a file.

Comment: If my code works for you, go ahead and accept my answer, please.